# C, pthreads initialized in loop does not execute assigned function properly despite mutex

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex, pthread-key-create

I am having trouble debugging my C program where the goal is to create 5 threads and have each of them working on size-2 chunks of an array of length 10. The goal is to get the sum of that array. My actual program is a little less trivial than this as it takes dynamic array sizes and thread counts but I tried simplifying it to this simple problem and it still does not work.

ie.,

array = {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10}

then thread1 works on array[0] and array [1]

and thread2 works on array[2] and array[3]

etc...

thread5 works on array[8] and array[9]

However when i run my code, I get weird results, even when using a mutex lock.

For example, this is one of my results when running this program.

```
Thread #1 adding 3 to 0 New sum: 3
Thread #1 adding 4 to 3 New sum: 7
Thread #2 adding 5 to 7 New sum: 12
Thread #2 adding 6 to 12        New sum: 18
Thread #3 adding 7 to 18        New sum: 25
Thread #3 adding 8 to 25        New sum: 33
Thread #4 adding 9 to 33        New sum: 42
Thread #4 adding 9 to 42        New sum: 51
Thread #4 adding 10 to 51       New sum: 61
Thread #4 adding 10 to 61       New sum: 71
Sum: 71
```

First of all, why are there no tabs before the "New sum" for the first 3 lines? (see my printf log in calculate_sum function). And more importantly, why is thread0 never executing it's job and why is thread 4 executing twice?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct {
    int start, end, thread_number;
    int *data;
} Func_args;

static pthread_mutex_t mutex;
static int sum = 0;

void *calculate_sum(void *args) {

    int *arr = ((Func_args *)args)->data;
    int i = ((Func_args *)args)->start;
    int end = ((Func_args *)args)->end;
    int t_id = ((Func_args *)args)->thread_number;

    while (i < end) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
        printf("Thread #%d adding %d to %d\t", t_id, arr[i], sum);
        sum += arr[i++];
        printf("New sum: %d\n", sum);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }

    return NULL;
}

#define NUM_THREAD 5
#define ARRAY_LEN 10

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int array[ARRAY_LEN] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    pthread_t tid[NUM_THREAD];
    int i, pos = 0;

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++) {
        Func_args args;
        args.data = array;
        args.thread_number = i;
        args.start = pos;
        pos += 2;
        args.end = pos;
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, calculate_sum, &args);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < NUM_THREAD; i++)
        pthread_join(tid[i], NULL);

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    printf("Sum: %d\n", sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "why are there no tabs before the "New sum" for the first 3 lines?" - there are.

Answer (score 4):

You are passing each thread a pointer to an object that might get destroyed before the thread starts.

`args` is local, so it gets destroyed when the program exits the scope it's declared in - that is, at the end of the `for` loop body.

The thread might takes a few moments to start up, so if the thread starts after that, it will access a destroyed object - in practice, the memory will have been reused to store the next thread's values.

You can fix it by dynamically allocating the thread data with `malloc` (and remembering to `free` it in the thread or if pthread_create fails).

Comment: Oh right! That was my original implementation but didn't like the thought of malloc and freeing every time so I went with this! Ok that makes sense, I will go try that!

Comment: @vgbcell You could also use a local array, and pass each thread a pointer to a different array element (and make sure the array doesn't get destroyed until all threads are done with their parts of the array)